# Variables in Standard ML change if a new function declaration,was apllied by using the changed variable

Tags: variables, sml, ml

See the following code where I tried out how already been declared variable x acts after being newly bound and then used within a function declaration. Why it is acting like this?

```
- val x = 2;
val x = 2 : int
- fun addx y = y + x;
val addx = fn : int -> int
- addx(5);
val it = 7 : int
- val x = 5;
val x = 5 : int
- addx(5);
val it = 7 : int
- subx y = y - x;
- fun subx y = y - x;
val subx = fn : int -> int
- subx(7);
val it = 2 : int
- 3 + x;
val it = 8 : int
- addx(10);
val it = 12 : int
```

Comment: Why would the result be something else? Maybe say what you find surprising about the above, and why you expect a different outcome.

Comment: It sounds like you are a beginner to functional programming. Are you expecting `x` to always refer to one specific global mutable variable?

Comment: You are creating several things with the same name, and the functions use the value of the most recent binding. You can't change the value in a binding.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a combination of two features: immutability and variable shadowing. Variables are immutable, and cannot be reassigned to new values. But SML does allow you to **shadow** variable bindings, meaning that you are allowed to reuse an existing variable name for a new purpose (within a new lexical scope).

In the code you wrote, you used the name `x` twice for two different variables. The second declaration of `x` *shadows* the first, i.e., any code in the lexical scope that follows which mentions `x` is referring to the new declaration, not the old one. (Because of this possible confusion, some people consider variable shadowing to be bad code style.)

We can rename the second declaration to make everything much clearer:

```ml
- val x = 2;
val x = 2 : int
- fun addx y = y + x;
val addx = fn : int -> int
- addx(5);
val it = 7 : int
- val DIFFERENT_VARIABLE = 5;
val DIFFERENT_VARIABLE = 5 : int
- addx(5);
val it = 7 : int
- fun subx y = y - DIFFERENT_VARIABLE;
val subx = fn : int -> int
- subx(7);
val it = 2 : int
- 3 + DIFFERENT_VARIABLE;
val it = 8 : int
- addx(10);
val it = 12 : int
```

Comment: It may be a good idea to not refer to immutable bindings as "variables." This (admittedly common) practice leads to a lot of incorrect expectations, in my experience.

Comment: I guess my take is that to learn a programming language, you have to learn the lingo of the community which uses that language. It would be a disservice to SML newcomers to avoid the term "variable". Especially because the design of SML is so heavily influenced by mathematical notation (i.e., SML variables are essentially the same as mathematical variables).

Comment: I find it confuses people because so many come from previous programming experience where "variables" are by default just that: _variable_; whereas SML bindings (and those in most functional programming languages) are immutable by default.

Comment: SML variables do vary, just as mathematical variables do: if I define a function `f(x)`, then the meaning of `f(x)` varies depending on what is substituted for the variable `x`.  In other words, the meaning of `x` varies by callsite.

Comment: I agree that this confuses people who come from an imperative background. But IMO, overcoming that confusion is a necessary part of the learning process. It's much better to hit it head-on, than to avoid it.

The same sort of confusion arises when a person with mathematical background learns programming for the first time and sees something like `x = x+1` in Python. ;)

Comment: When I was taught SML we were told to use the word "identifier" instead of variable. I think it is a good alternatives if you want to make a distinction between immutable variables and mutable variables.